# Different way to define the integral of a function

Tags: real-analysis

The following exercise appeared in my examination which i could not solve completely.

> Let $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ be a continuous function.For each $n \in \mathbb N$, $ 1 \leq k \leq 2^n$,let $I_{k,n}=f^{-1}([\frac{k-1}{2^n},\frac {k}{2^n}])$.Since $I_{k,n}$ is compact it is a union of pairwise disjoint closed intervals and therefore $ \vert I_{k,n} \vert $,the sum of the lengths of those intervals makes sense.Show that $$\sum_{k=1}^{2^n} \frac {k}{2^n} \vert I_{k,n} \vert \to \int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx$$

It is clear that $U(f) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac {k}{2^n} \vert I_{k,n} \vert$ but i think this does not tell much.Any hints/ideas to solve this?

Comment: A compact set need not be a union of intervals.

Comment: @zhw. Example please?

Comment: The Cantor set for one.

Comment: Also in your sum k should go to 2^n

Comment: Why isn't the Cantor set a union of disjoint closed intervals? ($[a,a]=\{a\}$ is a closed interval.)

Comment: @smcc I assumed  the union was countable.

Comment: This is getting a bit silly. Every set is the union of singletons, which tells us nothing.

Comment: Seems you have a bone to pick with whoever wrote that exam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claimed result fails, even in the simplest cases. Take $f\equiv 1/2.$ Set $n=3$ just to see what's going on. Then the sum in question equals

$$\frac{4}{8}\cdot |f^{-1}([3/8,4/8])| + \frac{5}{8} \cdot |f^{-1}([4/8,5/8])| = \frac{1}{2}\cdot 1 + \frac{5}{8}\cdot 1 = 1 + \frac{1}{8}.$$

In fact the sum in question will $= 1 + 1/2^n$ for any $n$ by the same reasoning. So the sums $\to 1 \ne 1/2 = \int_0^1 f.$

Comment: Skimming over the counterexample -- wouldn't a quick "fix" be to have $[(k-1)/2^n, k/2^n)$ in the original question? ($[a,b)$ instead of $[a,b]$)

Comment: You probably want $((k-1)/2^n,k/2^n]$ but yes, that seems to be right because we want disjointness. But then the inverse images need not be compact (although compactness didn't seem to help at all). The problem is badly misstated I think.

Comment: Yes, it looks like it. Either the original question, or the recollection of it written down by the OP.

Comment: @zhw. Although the problem which i have asked is exactly the same as given in question paper but i think something is wrong with the question.So i am deleting this question.thank you!

Comment: @zhw. It seems like i cannot delete the question because there is an answer of the question.So i'd request you to delete the answer so that i could delete the question to avoid the unnecessary pain for the future readers of the question.

Comment: @Dontknowanything the question is fine -- leave it. It is a good example of how subtle an issue defining sensible quadrature rules can be.